# Как исправить ошибку импорта данных в кодировке CP-1251: ORA-12899: value too large for column

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8, импорт

Есть дамп БД с кодировкой CP-1251 и там есть кириллица. Нужно импортирвать этот дамп в БД с кодировкой UTF-8.

При запуске импорта через утилиту `impdp` получаю вот такую ошибку:

> KUP-11007: conversion error loading table "main"."address"
> ORA-12899: value too large for column 'address' (actual: 2, maximum: 1)

Создавать БД с кодировкой CP-1251 не удобно. Нужно выполнить импорт в UTF-8.

Как решить проблему без смены кодировки самой целевой БД?

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя <strike>перелить литровочку в поллитровик</strike> записать два байта в один.

[CP-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) это однобайтная кодировка, например, символ "Б" в ней представлен одним байтом. В UTF-8 этот же символ представлен двумя байтами:

```
select  
    dump (convert ('Б',  'CL8MSWIN1251','AL32UTF8'), 16) cp1251, 
    dump ('Б', 16) utf8 
from dual
/
CP1251          UTF8               
--------------- -------------------
Typ=1 Len=1: c1 Typ=96 Len=2: d0,91
```

Наглядно, что происходит в данном случае:

```
create table t1 (a varchar2(1))
/
insert into t1 values ('Б')
```

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "ME"."T1"."A" (actual: 2, maximum: 1)

Импорт делает тоже самое, он знает кодировку данных дампа и целевой БД, формирует запросы вставки с перекодировкой символьных колонок, но запросы завершаются ошибкой - записать колонки в кодировке целевой БД он не может.

Рекомендуемое решение - следует в целевий БД *все колонки*, участвующее в импорте и потенциально содержащие кириллические символы, изменить на символьную семантику, то есть чтобы кол-во символов считалось *посимвольно*, а не *побайтно* (по умолчанию):

```
alter table t1 modify a varchar2(1 char) 
/
insert into t1 values ('B');

1 row inserted.
```